# simplexml_load_file not working for my PHP codes which was used to insert data from XML to MYSQL

Tags: php

I know that there are quite a few questions related to this but I can't seem to find the solution for my error.

I'm having problems with simplexml_load_file for my file (hourlyx.php)

Here's how the codes looks like :

```
//insert into db
$st = $con->prepare("Insert Into hourlyxweather(day_of_week_utc, time, date, wx, day_night,datetime) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//variables declared below          
$st->bind_param('ssssss', $day_of_week_utc, $time1, $date1, $wx,$day_night, $datetime);

$hourly= simplexml_load_file("hourly.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Here's a sample of the data in hourly.xml :

```
<hourly_summary>
            <day_of_week_utc>Wednesday</day_of_week_utc>
            <time_utc>2016-08-17 15:00:00</time_utc>
            <temp_C>29</temp_C>
            <dewp_C>26</dewp_C>
            <app_temp_C>34</app_temp_C>
            <rh_pct>84</rh_pct>
            <wx>Partly cloudy</wx>
            <wx_code>102</wx_code>
            <wx_icon_url>http://content.wdtinc.com/images/wxicons/night/partlycloudy.jpg</wx_icon_url>
            <wx_icon_url_png>http://content.wdtinc.com/images/wxicons_png/night/partlycloudy.png</wx_icon_url_png>
            <day_night>night</day_night>
            <pop>0</pop>
            <sky_cov_pct>59</sky_cov_pct>
            <wnd_dir_degs>160</wnd_dir_degs>
            <wnd_dir>SSE</wnd_dir>
            <wnd_spd_kph>14</wnd_spd_kph>
            <visibility_m>11300</visibility_m>
</hourly_summary>
```

I tried running the codes today but it showed this error :

[image: PHP error log]

I'm not sure what this error mean as I have been running the PHP code multiple times previously and it was working well.

This is C:\scripts\hourlyx.php on line 19 :

```
$hourly= simplexml_load_file("hourly.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Comment: it works fine on php 5.6.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, your XML simply isn’t what you said it is.

You seem to have started your document with `<hourly_summaries>`, and ended it with `</hourly_summary>` – that won’t work of course, the tag name in the starting and ending tag of an element must match.

(Whether the second message about extra content is related to the first error, or something independent, you’ll have to see. Check if your document contains any extra data outside of the root element.)